# How to fix "missing catch or finally after try" if i already put catch?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, text-to-speech

Heres my code

```
const {getAudioUrl} = require("google-tts-api") 
const langlist = ["en", "id"]

let language = args[0]
if(langlist.find(c => c === language)) {
if(!language) return message.reply("Please enter the language") 

if(!args[1]) return message.reply("Please enter the text")
const text = args.slice(1).join(" ")
if(text.length > 200) return message.reply('You cant input a text with over 200 characters')
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
if(!voiceChannel) return message.reply(" Please enter a voice channel") 

                                    
const audioURL = await getAudioUrl(text, {
lang: language, 
slow: false, 
host: 'https://translate.google.com', 
timeout: '150000'
 })


 try {
   voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
     const dispatcher = connection.play(audioURL)
     dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
       voiceChannel.leave()
     })
   })
 }
} else { return message.reply(`That language is not supported, the current supported language : [${langlist.join(", ")}]`); }
   
catch(err){
console.log(err)
message.channel.send("There is an error")}
}
}
```

I'm searching on internet but their problem if the try don't have catch, but i already have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `catch` statement is outside the `if` block that has the `try` block. This is what I did to fix the error:

1. Move the `catch` block closer to the `try`.
2. Remove extra `}` that were causing errors.
3. Fix the indentation.

Here's the code:

```js
const {getAudioUrl} = require("google-tts-api") 
const langlist = ["en", "id"]

let language = args[0]
if(langlist.find(c => c === language)) {
    if(!language) return message.reply("Please enter the language") 

    if(!args[1]) return message.reply("Please enter the text")
    const text = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if(text.length > 200) return message.reply('You cant input a text with over 200 characters')
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
    if(!voiceChannel) return message.reply(" Please enter a voice channel") 

                                        
    const audioURL = await getAudioUrl(text, {
        lang: language, 
        slow: false, 
        host: 'https://translate.google.com', 
        timeout: '150000'
    })


    try {
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            const dispatcher = connection.play(audioURL)
            dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            voiceChannel.leave()
            })
        })
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        message.channel.send("There is an error")
    }
} else {
    return message.reply(`That language is not supported, the current supported language : [${langlist.join(", ")}]`);
}
```

---

A tip to avoid this kind of error: **indent properly!**

If you had indented all of your code, it would have been so much easier to read and therefore finding the error would have been really quick (and you wouldn't even need to ask Stack Overflow).

> "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute." - Harold Abelson

If you make your code easier to read, debugging, rewriting, maintaining, understanding, etc. will become much easier - for you, and everyone else.

Comment: Sorry the extra bracket for the command handler, i forgot to include that, anyway very much thanks for the help i forgot to make the catch closer